# Would it be possible to run a Blazor server app with WASI?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, wasi

I know that WASI is still experimental in Dotnet, but would it be possible to run a Blazor server app with WASI ?

I tried to add the wasi-wasm tag in the project file and adding the wasi-experimental workload without success. I see that in the Blazor server project it has this tag

and in the wasiconsole project

Comment: The following link is to a summer 2023 Microsoft demo where compiling a Blazor Server application to WebAssembly is mentioned but the details are skipped over https://youtu.be/gKX-cdqnb8I?t=370 There is a more recent blog post from Steve Sanderson which provides details on how to make C# calls between components written in C# and compiled to Wasm https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/wasm-component-sdk The absence of a tutorial showing Blazor Server running within a WASI host either indicates the toolchain is too fragmented at the moment or Microsoft/Wasm experts believe this is easy and obvious